# Ubuntu 18.04 install crashes on Windows 7 PC: cannot install GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, windows-7

OK, so a puzzle:  I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on an HP Compaq 6200 Pro (Small Form Factor) Windows 7 PC.  Initially, I wasn't sure whether the PC was using UEFI or Legacy BIOS:  the boot process seems a bit odd for BIOS--I have trouble trying to get to the traditional menus and settings (e.g., using F2, F12, DEL, etc.) during boot time--but after some digging in a Windows log and other detective work, all the indications were that the PC *was* using Legacy BIOS.  I resized my Windows partitions using an Ubuntu Live USB and GParted, to give myself some space for my Ubuntu installation, and then I tried to install Ubuntu in a side-by-side installation.

Unlike other times I've installed Ubuntu, the Live USB did not detect Windows:  it didn't *explicitly* offer me the option to do a side-by-side install.  So, I used the "Something Else" option to establish my own partitions (root, swap, and home) and arrange the setup.  I received a warning that there was no EFI partition and the install was likely to fail, which at first made me cancel and research further...but I couldn't find any evidence of the PC using UEFI, and so I restarted and proceeded.  Well, the install crashed during the installation of GRUB.  I had to shut down, reboot, re-establish the blank space for the partitions, and try again, this time setting up an explicit EFI area.  However, my installation crashed once more--again, during the installation of GRUB.  I should note that throughout all of this, at the various times I've had to boot to Windows 7, it has continued to boot and run normally.  So what the heck is going on with the Ubuntu install?

I know that Windows 7 was sort of a "transitory OS" in that some were installed on systems using BIOS, others with an early version of UEFI...so the only thing I can think of is that maybe I should have done the re-partitioning of my Windows partition from within Windows itself:  I'm wondering if there *WAS* some sort of UEFI in place and I messed it up and caused it to somehow revert to legacy BIOS.  But based on what [little?] I know, that doesn't seem possible:  my guess is that Windows would simply fail to boot if that happened, and besides, there were at least a couple of online guides that mentioned doing the re-partitioning the way I did (from the Ubuntu Live USB), so right now I can't see how that may have "broken" something.  What could I be missing?  THANKS!

Comment: If you [edit] your question and add detailed information about the partition setup on the computer, that would be most helpful. ISTR there's a graphical Windows Partition Manager or somesuch, a screenshot from that would be nice.

Comment: Check your BIOS settings again, maybe set a supervisor password to get more options.  What model machine are you using?  What you describe sounds like a UEFI capable machine with a legacy W7 install, with the capability to select a preference (UEFI vs legacy) when both are possible (and UEFI is prefered).

Comment: The PC is an HP Compaq 6200 Pro (Small Form Factor)...edited main post to reflect this additional detail.

Comment: Your Windows 7 must have been BIOS, and then trying to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode fails. Windows only boots in BIOS mode from MBR partitioned drives and only in UEFI mode from gpt partitioned drives. Ubuntu will let you install in UEFI mode to a BIOS install of Windows, but that will never work if on same drive. You can convert install to BIOS with Boot-Repair and advanced option to totally reinstall grub. But you have to boot installer in BIOS mode. You should have two boot options in UEFI/BIOS one time boot menu. Have you updated UEFI/BIOS?

Comment: Hello oldfred:  The only problem with your thought is that I *first* tried to install Ubuntu in BIOS mode, and it *still* failed (that was when I first got the warning about Ubuntu needing to have an EFI-boot partition, which was puzzling).  I only tried UEFI the second time around.  Based on your suggestion, I'm going to look for a boot-repair option on the Ubuntu Live USB.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is to install Xibuntu 32 bit version, first. It will repair GRUB and install Xubuntu for you. Then install Ibuntu 64 bit version. Only had to do thus two times. Best way for me.

Comment: Hello Christian...thanks for your response!  But I'm hoping there has to be an easier way to do this, otherwise I'll have to do two more downloads (of Xubuntu and Ibuntu) and THREE more installs (Ubuntu is my target system of choice for this PC)!  Is there some sort of specialized tool(s) in Xubuntu to fix this problem that Ubuntu doesn't have?

Comment: get into Live DVD / Live USB and use "Try Ubuntu" ....when you get into the desktop.Open the app-store and open Boot Repair.

Comment: or use these commands @ Terminal  -  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair

boot-repair

Comment: read this article -  https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Answer (score 0):

The prize goes to Christian-Bearsly-Clark (with a little help from me)!

This article he mentioned was instrumental, as well as the tool discussed in it: [howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot](https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/).  The tool is called boot-repair, and it reportedly fixes a variety of common problems that cause failures to boot in Ubuntu.  I followed the instructions, and that got Ubuntu booting smoothly...but automatically, without any choice from me (I'm used to the GRUB boot-time menu with timeout, which allows you to choose the OS to boot to, if you wish).  A little research enabled me to find how to fix that...from the terminal:

```
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

That will open up a text editor that will allow you to edit the grub configuration file as a superuser (simply trying to edit it normally with gedit or the likes won't work, as it's a system file).

- Change the line **GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden** to
  **GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu**
- Change the **GRUB_TIMEOUT=10** line if you like (the default is 10
  seconds)...that's how long GRUB will wait before booting into the
  default (Ubuntu)
- Select **^X Exit** (ctrl-X) when you're done.
- Ubuntu will then offer to save your edits to a temporary file, which
  is used to overwrite the original...make certain you use the default
  filename Ubuntu gives you!

When you're done, use **sudo update-grub** to rebuild grub's configuration using your changes.  Then, reboot!

Thanks to everyone for all your help!